# how to run SSMS as a different user?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssms, sql-server-2016, windows-server

I am running SSMS `as a different user` from my local machine and it works fine.

When I try to do the same, even using my own credentials, on `server01` I get the following error:
`access is denied`

I am currently in the `Administrators` group in that server:
[image]

The way to run ssms as a different user is:

1- right clink on the ssms icon if it is already running otherwise follow from 2
2- witht eh shift key pressed right click the ssms icon and it will give you the options as shown on the picture below.

[image]

considering the password is correct and I am `sysadmin` what could be missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you are running version 130. Apparently SSMS 2016 fails to run as different user as reported below. I have experienced this myself. Quite frustrating.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1315261c-0d9e-49bf-8334-6c0195015598/ssms-2016-fails-on-windows-10-version-1607-while-trying-to-execute-it-as-a-different-domain-user?forum=sqltools

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3009405/ssms-2016-fails-on-windows-10-version-1607-while-trying-to-execute-it-as-a-different-domain-user

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Windows account that you're using on your local machine has enough permission to launch SSMS, but that same Windows account does not have permission on the server. Grant the appropriate permission to the Windows account on the server to be able to launch SSMS, and then it should work fine.

Unless...you're referring to a SQL Server "cannot connect" error...then the answer is different. :)

Comment: my account is administrator on that server and also I am domain admin

Comment: But does the user you're trying to enter in the Run As... have permissions, too? Both accounts need rights to log in on the server.