# Replicaton - The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, scripting, troubleshooting

After creating a replication publication, I go ahead and create a subscription using the script below:

```
-----------------BEGIN: Script to be run at Publisher 'MY_PUBLISHER_SERVER'--------------
use [MY_PUBLICATION_DB]
exec sp_addsubscription 
 @publication = N'MY_PUBLICATION', 
 @subscriber = N'MY_SUBSCRIBER_SERVER', 
 @destination_db = N'ORCA_Repl_Sub', 
 @subscription_type = N'Push', 
 @sync_type = N'automatic', 
 @article = N'all', 
 @update_mode = N'read only', 
 @subscriber_type = 0



exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent 
 @publication = N'MY_PUBLICATION', 
 @subscriber = N'MY_SUBSCRIBER_SERVER', 
 @subscriber_db = N'ORCA_Repl_Sub', 
 @job_login = N'MY_COMPANY\sqlrpl', 
 @job_password = N'MYP455w0rd',
 @subscriber_security_mode = 1, 
 @frequency_type = 64, 
 @frequency_interval = 0, 
 @frequency_relative_interval = 0, 
 @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, 
 @frequency_subday = 0, 
 @frequency_subday_interval = 0, 
 @active_start_time_of_day = 0, 
 @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, 
 @active_start_date = 20190423, 
 @active_end_date = 99991231, 
 @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', 
 @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'
GO
--------------END: Script to be run at Publisher 'MY_PUBLISHER_SERVER'-----------------
```

to my surprise I get all the following errors when running the second procedure:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep_internal, Line 255 [Batch Start Line 14]
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_MSadd_repl_job_unsafe, Line 376 [Batch Start Line 14]
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.
```

[image]

Basically [Replication Scripts Stopped Working..](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f2a0ca7-4b7a-4cb2-9450-a7dedb9d8bfd/replication-scripts-stopped-working?forum=sqlreplication)

How could be a solution for this?
where to find more information about these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [re-connected to sql-server using the credentials of my replication agent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/184909/22336) - which is a `sysadmin` on my publication server, and `db_owner` on my subscription database at my subscription server.

1 - right click on the ssms icon

[image]

2 - on the SSMS option above, press shift + right click and choose the `Run as a different user`

[image]

3 - add the credentials of the `different user` - in my case it was my replication agent account

and it all worked fine after that, as you can see on the picture below:

[image]